# Is it possible to control the Spotify client via another Java program?

Tags: java, client, spotify

I'd like to give my bot a command like play (the songs name) on Spotify. After that the bot should open the  Spotify client and play the song . The bot should be able to play the next or the previous song in a playlist and toggle start/stop playing . It's probably going to be pretty similar to Amazon Echo. 
For example: https://youtu.be/WZ5Snilpj88
If you didn't understand my problem. 
Short version: I need to control the Spotify deskop client via a java program.

I would appreciate any help.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

## Controlling Spotify

Yes, there are even two ways to communicate with Spotify. On one side there is the Web 
API and on the other side there is the local Spotilocal API. While the Web API is documented and can be used everywhere, the Spotilocal API can only be used with a local Spotify instance and is not documented.

Both APIs would be eligible for your project because you start Spotify on the same PC.

#### The Spotify Web API

The Spotify Web API is a RESTful Service with the base address `https://api.spotify.com`. It's well documented and has most features as the app. This is the only supported and official way to communicate with Spotify.

- [Spotify | Documentation](https://beta.developer.spotify.com/documentation/web-api/)
- [Spotify | All Endpoints](https://beta.developer.spotify.com/documentation/web-api/reference/)

#### The Spotilocal API

The Spotilocal API is a locally hosted RESTful Service. The Spotify desktop application starts a small web server in the background. The port is generally inconsistent and can start at `4370` up to `4380`. This whole API is actually for the Spotify web widget, but can also be used for local actions.

- [Medium | Explanation 1](https://medium.com/@bengreenier/hijacking-spotify-web-control-5014b0a1a360)
- [CGBYStrom | Explanation 2](http://cgbystrom.com/articles/deconstructing-spotifys-builtin-http-server/)

#### Summary

I recommend to use the official Spotify Web API and don't recommend the Spotilocal API at all. Only if an authorization is not possible, you should use the Spotilocal API.