# Is there any way to communicate with the Spotify Client locally?

Tags: spotify

I need to access the play/pause status and accurate track position, and ideally the current and next track ID as well.  There used to be the [spotilocal API](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/50221789/is-it-possible-to-control-the-spotify-client-via-another-java-program) which would allow this, but that has since been removed in favor of their [Web API](https://developer.spotify.com/documentation/web-api/).  Accurate timing with the Web API is impossible due to network latency.

Is there any way to access this information?

One thing caught my eye in [TCPView](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/sysinternals/downloads/tcpview) - Spotify has two TCP listeners attached on dynamic ports.  One of these appears to be for communication with other Spotify clients on the same network (it had an established connection with my phone while I was investigating).  I'm not sure what the other is for, but all I know is that if you connect to it with TELNET, the connection opens, the server spews out JSON data: `{"type":"Tier1","version":"1.0"}` and immediately closes the connection.

Other things I have tried so far:

- Running a very old version of the client where the spotilocal API still existed - it immediately forces an auto-update.
- Running a proxy to sniff for requests where the client is updating the Spotify servers of the play position.  Doesn't work - uses HTTP CONNECT (would only work if it transparently issued requests)
- Starting up my own instance of the [Spotify Web Player](https://developer.spotify.com/documentation/web-playback-sdk/) and connecting back to my application to provide the necessary data - the SDK is still in Beta and I have found it to be very unstable/unreliable.

Comment: Did you ever find a solution to this?  I've created my own websocket server which uses MacOS's OSXScript to probe the Spotify app and returns it back to my geekscript/Übersich desktop widget.  Not the best solution, but if I can plug into Spotify instead that would be fantastic.

Comment: @GuyPark no, I haven't found a solution. Spotify has since made significant stability improvements to the Web Playback SDK, so I've played with that some, communicating with my local software via a WebSocket. For your purposes, you may be able to use the Spotify API, just spin up an HTTP server to handle OAuth, then just refresh your token and occasionally poll the API endpoint to get your listening status. Still not an ideal solution, but it's probably more reliable. Supremely annoyed with Spotify for removing the local API.

Comment: Thanks Eric.  Yeah ended up giving up and using my current little NodeJS websocket script to use a bash/OSAScript to poll the program and to send through JSON.  Mainly I was hoping to make my GeekScript/Übersicht widget more direct to spotify than having to have two extra things running.  I have a feeling there is a way as my phone can interact with my desktop spotify, but would require weeks of WireSharking and deconstructing, which just don't have time for.  If it's for Mac, let me know and I can pass what I built.